# Setting up eclipse in OS X (C++) ERROR: launch failed, binaries not found?

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, compiler-errors

There are a million questions on this topic,and I have read all of them. I have installed eclipse juno on my computer, I run OS X Yosemite.

I just want to run a simple hello world program. But I can't,I don't know why.

I do build the project ,even if I do I get errors for everything, so running boost is out of question.

I used to use codeblocks, until it started crashing every 5 minutes,I cant work that way anymore.

I don't know what other details to give,I have the command line tools xcode installed,i have followed almost every blog and questions addressing this,I still can?t get it right.

EDIT:

language: C++
ERROR: launch failed binary not found

I have xcode command lines,jre,gcc.

Comment: What language is the Hello World? Do you actually "get errors for everything"? Can you post some of those?

Comment: why not installing the latest Eclipse (Luna) instead of a two years old version (Juno -> Kepler -> Luna)?

Comment: So I installed eclipse luna,and I get the same(launch binaries not found) ,I got errors at all the header files previously,now I dont get any errors,i just get aunch binaries not found.(I have built the project btw),the language is C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO I solved my queries, here it goes:

1. *I realised that I first had to build my project once(just once) and then running it would be enough*
2. *I still got the same error launch failed, i realised that eclipse could not locate the binary file that was built, I tried indicating the file directly,did not work, but what worked was setting the eclipse Parser as the mach-o-parser instead of the default elf.*
3. *Another problem was to set the compiler from GNU to the mac compiler.*
4. *For some people,downloading the 32-bit version worked,you could try this out.*
5. *I also updated my version of eclipse from juno to luna(dint make a difference,did it anyway)*

**NOTE:** for the above you need to have installed the JRE and Xcode command line tools

P.S I did not elaborate more as an individual google search will give you detailed steps,I wanted to indicate the problems and solutions that worked for me,the steps are already available.